# I cannot get two programs to run together

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

I have been trying unsuccessfully to get both of these scripts to work as one script.  I am trying to run this in a Windows 7 environment.

```
# Beginning of Program One

import webbrowser
import time

tme = "Start time - " + time.strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %I:%M %S")
print(tme)

new = 2 # open in a new tab, if possible

# open a public URL, in this case, the webbrowser docs
url = "http://www.foxsports.com/nba"
webbrowser.open(url,new=new)


# END OF PROGRAM 1

# BEGINNING OF PROGRAM 2
import win32gui
import win32ui
import win32con
import win32api
import os
import re
import xlrd
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time


 # WindowMgr - allows me to send control to the Chrome Webpage 
class WindowMgr:
"""Encapsulates some calls to the winapi for window management"""
def __init__ (self):
    """Constructor"""
    self._handle = None

def find_window(self, class_name, window_name = None):
    """find a window by its class_name"""
    self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
    '''Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows'''
    if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) != None:
        self._handle = hwnd

def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
    self._handle = None
    win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

def set_foreground(self):
    """put the window in the foreground"""
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)


# Activate the webpage
w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*Videos*")
w.set_foreground()

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("^a") # CTRL+A
shell.SendKeys("^c") # CTRL+C

try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
clip_text = root.clipboard_get()
print (clip_text)

# END OF PROGRAM2
```

Comment: What traceback are you getting?

Comment: Please give a [mcve], as it stands it's unclear what exactly the problem is.

Comment: It is complete.  There are 2 scripts in the code above - and there are comments documenting where the scripts begin and end.  I am trying to pen a webpage - activate it- and then do a CTRL A and then a CTRL C to copy the text on the webpage.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain on what you want to achieve with this program?
From what I can tell based on the code, you wish to open `http://www.foxsports.com/nba` in a web browser tab,
 then you set the focus to this browser and then you do a `CTRL + A` to select all text in the page and then `CTRL + C` to copy said text in to your clipboard.
Finally you extract what you copied and print it.

If my assumption is correct that you only want the text of a webpage for whatever reason then I would recommend using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) to get the source and parsing the source using [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

An example:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
source = urllib.urlopen("http://www.foxsports.com/nba").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, parse_only=SoupStrainer("a"))  # a is anchor tag in <a href=""></a>
links_list = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links_list[:10]:
    print link.text
```

This finds all links on the page and prints the text associated with just the first 10 of them. You can adjust what data(based on tags) you want to parse using `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thanks Robert - exactly what I am trying to achieve - will give this a shot!